# GAE Python Resource Manager API Error "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My goal is to programmatically create appengine projects and then deploy an app from source control.

I WAS trying to use code I found here: http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource-manager-api.html

```
>>> from google.cloud import resource_manager
>>> client = resource_manager.Client()

>>> # List all projects you have access to
>>> for project in client.list_projects():
...     print(project)

>>> # Create a new project
>>> new_project = client.new_project('your-project-id-here',
...                                  name='My new project')
>>> new_project.create()
```

Which produces the error: "The caller does not have permission". But then I realized it is in Alpha (invitation only) which *probably* explains the error (way to be confusing, Google!).

I also found this page that has different code (Click on Python Client Library), but I don't know how to use it:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-project

Code:

```
...

operation = crm.projects().create(
    body={
        'project_id': flags.projectId,
        'name': 'my project'
}).execute()

...
```

I'm guessing the "rm" in "crm" stands for resource manager, so is this what I'm looking for or is it something unrelated?

Maybe my goal is just not possible yet without an Alpha invitation.

## EDIT

### Created a new question here with updated code:

[GAE (Python) Cloud Resource Manager - Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666906/gae-python-rest-to-cloud-resource-manager-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That libraries documentation is misleading and also incorrect. It is misleading in telling you that your authentication is handled by using the `gcloud` commands. That might work fine for local development or for situations where your run that command ON the actual server running the code, but that is not the case on App Engine. It is incorrect in that Cloud Resource Manager is not in alpha, but rather is generally available for everyone.

You need to set up OAuth client ID credentials in the Cloud Platform Console, and then set up an OAuth login flow where the end user can grant your application access to creating projects on the user's behalf.

Start with the App Engine Admin API [documentation for creating applications programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/creating-an-application).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, BrettJ. It was confusing to me that the documentation recommended running `gcloud auth login` to create credentials for my app. I understand that the Cloud Resource Manager" is not in Alpha, but the projects.create() function itself is. I do not want to include the end user in this creation process. I want all of my sub-apps to be created under my own account. All I want the end user to experience is a loading animation. Is this possible?

Comment: The projects.create() method is NOT alpha, it is GA. Individual client libraries might be at different levels, but they all just wrap the REST API, which is GA. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create

Comment: You probably want to go with a service account authorization flow then if you want your account/project to maintain ownership of the created projects. Note that there is a limit of about 10 projects that by default a given account can have. You might have to request an increase in quota through support if you need more than that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the service account authorization flow and contact Google to see if i can get a higher quota.